# SQL Server 2005 collation issue during installation

Tags: sql-server-2005, installation, collation

Every time I try to install SQL Server 2005 on to a Windows 7 machine it installs properly but the collation installed is `sql_latin1_general_as` instead of `sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as`. I have read somewhere that this might be due to the fact that the regional setting for that machine is set to `English - United Kingdom`, so I double checked it to make sure that regional settings is set to `English - United States`. Still, after the installation I checked the server properties from Management Studio and saw the collation installed is `sql_latin1_general_ci_as` instead of `sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as`.

What am I doing wrong here? Are there any other diagnostics steps to find out why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. there is [no collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250%28SQL.90%29.aspx) "sql_latin1_general_as"
2. there is [no collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250%28SQL.90%29.aspx) "sql_latin1_general_ci_as"
3. collation chosen during install [does depend on the control panel settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143508%28SQL.90%29.aspx)
4. The default collation for a clean install would be ["SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" for US English](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143508%28SQL.90%29.aspx):
5. The default for UK English is ["Latin1_General_CI_AS"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143508%28SQL.90%29.aspx)
6. SQL collations are legacy and should only be chosen for in-situ upgrades (IIRC)

Basically, choose "Latin1_General_CI_AS" (you have a choice) and make sure you read correctly before posting

Comment: He's installing a legacy product (SQL 2005), pretty sure SQL collations are his only option.  Wasn't the change to Windows collations made in SQL 2008 or am I remembering this wrong?

Comment: @mrdenny: I've linked to SQL 2005 BOL (Had to check myself) I've never installed SQL on a US English box so never seen the default of SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. UK English and Swiss German boxes both offer Latin1_General_CI_AS