# Design SQL Server 2008 new install ... which collation?

Tags: sql-server-2008, collation

A customer has a SQL Server 2005 instance, collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`, with 8 databases ... for a new application, we have been asked to install a SQL Server 2008 with collation `SQL_Latin1_General_BIN`.

In order to maintain a single database server, and then also by addressing the previous db migration to the new version, which instance collation should be adopted?

Thanks a lot

Bye,
Francesco

Answer (score 1):

The default collation is based on the Windows system locale of your server. `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` is usually the default collation for computers based in the North American locale. Collation can be changed if you have a reason for it, like: sorting order, case sensitivity, accent sensitivity, non-English characters, width.

Collation for a DB can be set at the time of the creation of the DB, so you can have a server that has DBs with different collations. The `Alter database` command can be used to change the collation of all newly created objects in the DB. I have used the default `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` all the time and have not had any issues, but then I do more DB administration that development.

Comment: The default collation is based on your regional settings. See http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7212/630

Comment: That is very good info. Thanks @gbn. It is hard to come by the experience of installing in different regions (countries).

Comment: I only found this out by testing for this answer...