# SQL Server 2012 : how to add missing collation

Tags: sql-server-2012, collation

When we run:

```
ALTER DATABASE abc COLLATE Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS ;
GO
```

we receive:

> Msg 448, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   Invalid collation 'Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'.

How can we add the `missing collation`?

Answer (score 2):

There never has been a "Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS": it is "Latin1_General_CI_AS" or "Latin1_General_100_CI_AS"

You may be confusing it with "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" which is legacy, basically.

Saying that, the collation offered at setup varies based on your regional settings. See [SQL Server 2005 collation issue during installation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/7211/630) for more (I've no idea why US English locale offers a "legacy" SQL collation)

```
SELECT * FROM ::fn_helpcollations() FH WHERE name LIKE '%Latin%_CI_AS'
```

Answer (score 1):

The collation is not *missing* it is **invalid**. Try `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` instead.